# UITapGestureRecognizer for detecting which UIView was tapped on my screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `UITapGestureRecognizer` for detecting which UIView was tapped on my screen but for some reason it only detects the parent view tap, for example below code logs only parent views tag. How do i detect subview taps which are present on main view. Please suggest.

```
Inside View did load :- 

UITapGestureRecognizer *viewTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionForViewTapped:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:viewTapRecognizer];


-(void) actionForViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    NSLog(@"view tapped");
    UIView *view = sender.view;
    NSLog(@"view tag is %lu", view.tag); //Always prints parent view tag. 

    if(view.tag == 10){
        NSLog(@"tag1 tapped"); // not called
    }
    if(view.tag == 20){
        NSLog(@"tag 2 tapped"); // not called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect subview using following code, I just tested creating sample project.

```
-(void) actionForViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    NSLog(@"view tapped");
    UIView *view = sender.view;
    CGPoint loc = [sender locationInView:view];
    UIView* subview = [view hitTest:loc withEvent:nil];
    NSLog(@"view tag is %lu", subview.tag); //will print Subview tag.

    if(view.tag == 10){
        NSLog(@"tag1 tapped");  
    }
    if(view.tag == 20){
        NSLog(@"tag 2 tapped");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `UIGestureRecognizer` is to be used with a single view.

If you want to use `UIGestureRecognizer` you will have to create one for each view, calling the same method.